# R increase curve line width to 150%

Tags: r, plot

I encounter an issue to use high level plot function `curve()` to draw the curve of sin() from `0` to `2*pi`, but the additional requirement i am not sure how to deal with, it ask to **increase the width of curve line to 150% of original width**.

The original curve() function which able to draw the picture without increasing curve line to 150% width.
`curve(sin, 0, 2 * pi)`, effect in RStudio as below:
[image]

I tried with `curve(sin, 0, 2 * pi, lwd = 1.5)`, but seems **not work**, seems `lwd` only works for integer value, like `lwd = 2`, `lwd = 3`... so how can i increase the width of curve line to 150% of original width ?

Comment: `lwd` not only works for integer values. `lwd = 1.5` indeed makes the line bolder, but it's not obvious. If the **width of the curve line** means the wavelength, then it'll be a math problem.

Comment: Thanks, Tsai, for confirm `lwd` not only work for integer, like you mention, its quite implicit to observe the difference between default width and `lwd = 1.5`, that's why i suspect if `lwd` not work against non-integer, yeah, this question not for wavelength, so i think this comment already resolve the puzzle.